# Creating custom URLs with TYPO3, RealURL and tt_news

Tags: url, typo3, tt-news, realurl

Im still not understanding very well how the configuration of RealURL works. So far Im getting my news with this format:

http://www.mysite.com/games/detail/date/2012/01/01/game-1/

But Id like it to be able to customize the URL as I want, like:

http://www.mysite.com/games/WhateverIwanthere/

I have a page with the LIST view (id=3) and a child page with the SINGLE view (id=13)

This is my realurl_autoconf.php: http://pastebin.com/31s9uZDb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get rid date params from your tt_news links see [tt_news docs](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/tt_news/3.2.1/view/1/4/) and find `Settings for Links` section
2. Put LIST view and SINGLE view on the same page and switch the views with TypoScript (there are snippets in the net so I don't writ it here)
3. Use [fixedPostVars](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/05/realurl-made-easy-part-1.html) of `RealURL` to avoid redundant 'detail' word

With this scenario you'll be able to display:

http://domain.tld/games/ - LIST view

http://domain.tld/games/one-two-three/ - SINGLE view of *One Two Three* game

Comment: Thanks Marcus. You are my Typo3 hero.

Comment: TYPO3 not Typo3 ;) always! http://typo3.org/the-brand/style-guide/the-typo3-spelling/